# Not able to see gitlab-runner template in openshift project

Tags: gitlab, openshift

I have created eval login for OpenShift online and GitLab. (None of this installed on my premises)

1) Created a project in OpenShift and created abc project in it.

2) Imported template in OpenShift via below command

```
oc apply -f gitlab-runner.yml
```

3) However in that project (abc) when i go to brows catalog I can not see imported gitlab-runner template.

When I go to search option and select template I can see imported template but not in project namespace.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: For a template loaded into project, you need to select the 'Select From Project' option, not 'Browse Catalog'.

Comment: where do I see this option, once I go into project I didn't see that option or `Add to project` option.

Comment: If you use 3.11, it is under 'Add to Project' menu drop down top right of overview page for a project. What OpenShift version are you using?